# How to make width start shrinking from the Left instead of right?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, width, css-shapes

1- I'm trying to make an image vanish by animating its container (position: fixed) width from 100% to 0% but it starts from the right, I want to make it start from the left.
I tried many things -like change page direction or to set the div right: 0px; instead of left: 0px; - but it didn't work.
How can I do that?

2- I want the div to have the shape of a circle while the width is shrinking and I used

```
border-bottom-right-radius: 500px;
border-top-right-radius: 500px;
```

to achieve that but at the end of the animation it doesn't take a circular shape.
What is a good approach to make it stay a circle?

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("sick")[0].style.animation = "move3 3s linear forwards";
```

```css
.sick {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 150%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  background: url('http://cfile10.uf.tistory.com/image/2649725057B9A2BB0CE4EE') no-repeat;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 500px;
  border-top-right-radius: 500px;
}

@keyframes move3 {
  0% {
    width: 100%;
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
    height: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0%;
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
    height: 100%;
  }
}

.explain {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="sick">

</div>
<div class="explain">
  <h1>Site Here</h1>
  <h2>Concept</h2>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kalidzakaria/xzs1r9qp/

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! I converted your fiddle into a "snippit" (the `<>` button in the question editor, you can edit the question to see it), which will let answerers see your code in one place, and copy it to their answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to animate the margin and the width to get the effect I think you want.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("sick")[0].style.animation = "move3 3s linear forwards";
```

```css
.sick {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 150%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  background: url('http://cfile10.uf.tistory.com/image/2649725057B9A2BB0CE4EE') no-repeat;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 500px;
  border-top-left-radius: 500px;
}

@keyframes move3 {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
    height: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 100%;
    width: 0%;
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
    height: 100%;
  }
}

.explain {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="sick">

</div>
<div class="explain">
  <h1>Site Here</h1>
  <h2>Concept</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Animate the `left` property:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("sick")[0].style.animation = "move3 3s linear forwards";
```

```css
.sick {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  background: url('http://cfile10.uf.tistory.com/image/2649725057B9A2BB0CE4EE') no-repeat;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 500px;
  border-top-left-radius: 500px;
}

@keyframes move3 {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
    height: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
    height: 100%;
  }
}

.explain {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="sick">

</div>
<div class="explain">
  <h1>Site Here</h1>
  <h2>Concept</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: You didn't get the idea of what I want to achieve here. please see the animation and then suggest what does the same but starts from the left.

Answer (score 0):

Coordinates always begin from the top left corner.

Using keyframes we can move the image's coordinates to the right at the same speed as its width getting smaller.

You already applied a circle effect using border-bottom-right-radius &
  border-top-right-radius, I just changed 'right' to 'left'.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("sick")[0].style.animation = "move3 3s linear forwards";"move3 3s linear forwards";
```

```css
.sick {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 150%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  background: url('http://cfile10.uf.tistory.com/image/2649725057B9A2BB0CE4EE') no-repeat;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 500px;
  border-top-left-radius: 500px;
}
@keyframes move3 {
  0% {
    width: 100%;
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
    height: 100%;
    left: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0%;
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
    height: 100%;
    left: 100%;
  }
}
.explain {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="sick">

</div>
<div class="explain">
  <h1>Site Here</h1>
  <h2>Concept</h2>
</div>
```